# How can I combine a static Rust library, low-level C FFI layer, and higher-level Swift bindings into a single binary framework bundle for iOS?

Tags: swift, rust, ffi, xcframework, uniffi

I'm using [UniFFI](https://mozilla.github.io/uniffi-rs/Overview.html) to generate Swift bindings for a Rust library.

*Following the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/uniffi-rs/swift/overview.html), I have:*

**1. Compiled the Rust library:**

- Once as a static library `libuniffi_example.a` for iOS devices (`aarch64-apple-ios`).
- Once as a fat static library `libuniffi_example.a` for the simulator (`x86_64-apple-ios` and `aarch64-apple-ios-sim`).

**2. Generated the Swift bindings** by running `uniffi-bindgen generate src/example.udl --language swift`. This outputs two things:

- A C header file `exampleFFI.h` declaring the low-level structs and functions for calling into Rust, along with a corresponding `exampleFFI.modulemap` to expose them to Swift.
- A Swift source file example.swift that imports the exampleFFI module and wraps it to provide the higher-level Swift API.

I've [managed to build](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle#Create-archives-for-frameworks-or-libraries) an XCFramework exposing the low-level C FFI layer defined in `exampleFFI.h` using:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework
    -library (...)/libuniffi_example.a -headers (...)/exampleFFI.h
    (...)
```

But when I use that XCFramework, I still need to include the generated `example.swift` source file in my project to access the higher-level Swift bindings.

*Ideally, I'd like to create a single [XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) that bundles everything necessary to access the Rust library via the generated higher-level Swift bindings directly.*

I specifically don't want the consumers of the library to have to manually include anything else than the XCFramework and be able to access the higher-level Swift bindings as generated in the `example.swift` source file.

Comment: Sounds way cool! The docs do say "you'll need both the generated .swift file and the corresponding .modulemap file" so I don't think you can avoid that.

Comment: But shouldn't it be possible to compile the generated swift file together with the rust library such that I have a binary that exposes the interface from the generated swift file?

Comment: I’m a little late to the conversation, but I’ve contributed to a project facilitating interop between rust and swift. There’s a cli tool which will convert you rust library into an XCframework and generate the necessary headers and swift code: https://chinedufn.github.io/swift-bridge/building/swift-packages/index.html consumers of the lib only need to import the swift binding